# Allow only one ip to connect to squid server

Tags: squid

I'm trying to allow only one ip to connect to the squid server but it seems it's not working I did ban all domains and allow only one domain but for the ip address it's not working here what I have done:

```
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
#http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
acl GOOD dstdomain .instagram.com
http_access allow GOOD
acl specialIP src 83.59.98.241
http_access allow specialIP
http_access deny all
```

Comment: Please clarify how it's "not working". Can all IPs use the proxy for all domains? Can the given IP talk to undesirable domains? Can undesirable IPs talk to the expected domain. There are many ways it can "not work", what exactly is yours?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the network mask. Try;

```
acl specialIP src 83.59.98.241/32
```

I am not clear what you want to do. Do you want a proxy only be able to be managed by one specific IP, or do you want a proxy, which denies access to all websites, except one (Instagram in this case)?